# Glassfish suddenly complaining of bogus port

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I've been running a Glassfish server under Eclipse Indigo.  It had been working just fine, but it suddenly refused to start, throwing this error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Starting GlassFish 3.1.2 at localhost".
port out of range:1118080
```

I didn't (knowingly) change anything about the server, so I'm guessing something got corrupted.  (I like Eclipse, but for as long as I've used it, occasional moments where it corrupts itself into uselessness have just been part of the experience.)  Does anybody have any advice on how I can get my Glassfish server back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, got it.  My domain.xml file (C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\config.xml, if you're hitting the same issue) got corrupted into oblivion.  Luckily, there was a .bak file in that directory that was still good.  Once I got that copied over (and corrected an issue with the password on my local DB server, which may or may not be related to the file getting corrupted in the first place), all was well.