# Default Glassfish 3.1.2.1 Install on Windows 8 port out of range when running via IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, jsf, intellij-idea, glassfish

I'm receiving the following error when trying to run a JSF App via IntelliJ IDEA with Glassfish.
[image]

The error shows the port out of range. The port is actually set to 63342. I'm curious if I should be using a set port in a lower range or if there is another way to resolve this error.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14284630/1530938

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution in two ways.

1. I tried the link provided by @kolossus to [Glassfish suddenly complaining of bogus port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284630/glassfish-suddenly-complaining-of-bogus-port). The resolution there seemed to work fine, however I found that...
2. The second solution was uninstalling Glassfish 3.x and installing Glassfish 4 as it appears to work seamlessly with IntelliJ IDEA 13 EAP.

Both are likely valid solutions, but I've stuck to solution #2.